# Month by Month Sales breakdown for top 10 Product for specific year Using Adventure Works Database in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, adventureworks

This is what I used to find the top 10 products for 2013 by total sum of sales. What is the easiest way to get a monthly breakdown of sales for a specific product ID for the year?

```
SELECT TOP 10 
    sod.ProductID, prd.Name, SUM(LineTotal) AS SumOfSales
FROM 
    Sales.SalesOrderDetail AS SOD
JOIN 
    Sales.SalesOrderHeader AS SOH ON SOD.SalesOrderID = SOH.SalesOrderID
JOIN
    Production.Product prd ON prd.ProductID = sod.ProductID
WHERE 
    SOH.OrderDate >= '01/01/2013' 
    AND SOH.OrderDate <= '12/31/2013'
GROUP BY 
    sod.ProductID, prd.Name
-- HAVING SUM(LineTotal) >= 2000000
ORDER BY 
    SUM(LineTotal) DESC
```

[Image of SQL output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Gn1J.png)

This is what I found after research but it says date_format is invalid

```
select date_format(sdate,'%M-%Y') as sdate,
sum(LineTotal) as 'netsales',
from Sales.SalesOrderDetail
where ProductID=782 and ModifiedDate >= '01/01/2013' and ModifiedDate <= '12/31/2013'
group by MONTH(sdate)
order by MONTH(sdate);
```

Comment: The title mentions SQL Server but you tagged SQLite. Tag the database that you actually use.

Comment: `date_format()` is not a SQL Server function, where did you find this in the documentation? Perhaps you need [format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql)

Comment: There is also the function PIVOT.

Answer (score 0):

Full list:

```
select *
from Sales.SalesOrderDetail
where ProductID=782 and DATEPART(YEAR,ModifiedDate) = 2013
```

You can use "*" or column names

Mothly Group List:

```
select datepart(month,ModifiedDate) as sdate,
sum(LineTotal) as 'netsales',
from Sales.SalesOrderDetail
group by datepart(month,ModifiedDate)
```

but you will see month number in sdate column.

Comment: select *
From Sales.SalesOrderDetail
sum(LineTotal) as 'netsales',
from Sales.SalesOrderDetail
where ProductID=782 and DATEPART(YEAR,ModifiedDate) = 2013
group by MONTH(sdate)
order by MONTH(sdate);

Like this?

Comment: No, if you are use "group by" you don't select "*". You should use column names instead of * and you must write in group by clause uncalculated columns.